# How can I find any number within a range of numbers using .includes()

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm writing a script to print out some info scraped from a certain website, I'm using the `.includes()` to find and print a number if that number falls inside a certain range from 1,000 to 100,000 but I can't figure out how to do that at all. The solution I'm trying right now is long and redundant and not even working.

**Code**

```
const numShare = await page.$$eval(".FormData", els =>
      els.find(e => e.textContent.includes(',000' || ',9' || ',8' || ',7' || ',6' || ',5' || ',4' || ',3' || ',2' || ',1'))
        .parentNode
        .textContent
        .trim()
    );

    return numShare;
```

One other thing I tried before is just using `.includes(',000')`, which worked but it only gave me stricly numbers with a comma and 3 zeros after it. What I want is for it to find any number from 1,000 to 100,000 or with the format "x,xxx to xxx,xxx". Would this be possible?

**Edit, what I'm trying**

````
      const shares = document.querySelector(".FormData");
      return {
        shares: shares.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent,
      };
    });
    
    return numShare.shares;```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the page, HTML or text you're working with, but I guess you have numbers with commas delimiting thousands places. So why not simply remove those commas and parse the strings to numbers, then compare normally?

```js
const numShare = await page.$$eval(".FormData", els =>
  els.find(e => {
    const n = +e.textContent.trim().replace(/,/g, "");
    return n >= 1000 && n <= 100000;
  })
  .parentNode
  .textContent
  .trim()
);
```

Runnable POC:

```js
const els = [...document.querySelectorAll(".FormData")];
const result = els.find(e => {
    const n = +e.textContent.trim().replace(/,/g, "");
    return n >= 1000 && n <= 100000;
  })
  .parentNode
  .textContent
  .trim(); 
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div>
  foo
  <div class="FormData">101,000</div>
</div>
<div>
  baz
  <div class="FormData">1,000</div>
</div>
```

Another approach is `const n = +e.textContent.match(/\d/g).join("");`, which pulls out all of the numbers and is more tolerant of extra characters like currency symbols and spaces.

As for why your current approach doesn't work, you're just asking whether it includes the first truthy value in your giant `||` chain:

```js
console.log(',000' || ',9' || ',8' || ',7' || ',6' || ',5' || ',4' || ',3' || ',2' || ',1');
```

Following up on the comments, it sounds like you need to select a field as well as test the range. Here's code that works on the example XML you provided:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  const url = "link to your XML file";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const text = await page.$eval(".SmallFormData", el =>
    el.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim()
  );
  const n = +text.match(/\d/g).join("");
  console.log(text, n >= 1000 && n <= 100000); // => 2,275 true
})()
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

This makes some assumptions about the page structure and may not be the most reliable way to select the Amount value, but in the absence of counterexamples I'll leave it stand as-is for now to avoid premature optimization.

Comment: This is the closest to what I want but I'm still having some complications here and there. You've helped me a lot with this so far, do you minf if we go to DMs so that I can run some things by you?

Comment: "I'm still having some complications here and there" is typically a symptom of a lack of minimal, reproducible example. Without one, I'm forced to guess rather than give verifiable, working code, and almost inevitably a lot of back-and-forth ensues. DMs defeat the purpose of the site--the point is to curate a resource for _future visitors_. I freelance 1:1 [for a rate](https://www.codementor.io/@ggorlen), or feel free to ask a new question or clarify your existing one. I watch the Puppeteer tag so I'll probably answer it if I can.

Comment: Alright, so although this does technically solve the problem, it ends up selecting the first value on the page that falls within the range, but what I want specifically is the Amount number. So for example in this [link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730464/000112760222025323/xslF345X03/form4.xml) the Amount I want to be displaying is 2,275 but what I end up getting is 1300 from the address above. So what I'm saying is, just like I was able to get the Price value, I want to get the Amount value as well

Comment: OK, so that sounds like a selector problem. If you're interested in that box, can you use something like `document.querySelector(".SmallFormData").parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling` to get just that one field, then apply the range logic given above? There's probably a more reliable selector than that, but you get the idea--pick the one box rather than all of them.

Comment: Ok, so I've edited the original post to how I'm implementing it. But I'm getting the error ``Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextElementSibling')`` and the console ends up displaying "undefined" for that value.

Comment: Look carefully: `document.querySelector(".SmallFormData")` versus `document.querySelector(".FormData")`.

Comment: Still getting the same error. And its actually `.FormData` I'm looking for, thats the actual number value. `.SmallFormData` is just the title/heading

Comment: Works fine for me. If you pop open [the page](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730464/000112760222025323/xslF345X03/form4.xml) and run that code 4 comments up in the console, you don't see the element selected? You add `.textContent` to get the content, and `.SmallFormData` is only used because `.FormData` isn't specific enough. Ultimately it leads to the "Amount" value you want. There are other ways of selecting it, you could take the nth `.FormData` or many other approaches.

Comment: This works. Thanks. But chances are I'll be asking more questions soon...

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you should just be able to parse it into a number and check its value. However, this is a little more complicated if the input can have commas in it like your question suggests. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with the surrounding code, but the parsing logic and checking logic should look something like this:

```js
function isInRange(stringNum) {
  const unformattedNum = stringNum.trim().split(", ").join("").split(",").join("");
  // Or if you're ok with only supporting browsers from 2020 onwards...
  // const unformattedNum = stringNumber.trim().replaceAll(", ", "").replaceAll("," , "");

  const parsed = parseInt(unformattedNum); // Assuming these are always whole numbers, otherwise use parseFloat instead
  return parsed >= 1000 && parsed <= 100000;
}
```

Then you could, for example, use that with the filter function to only get the items that are in range. e.g

```js
const numbersInRange = numbers.filter(isInRange);
// (If you haven't used array.filter before, it removes any items where the provided function returns false for it)
```

But you'll probably want to split the parsing and checking into two separate functions, unless you only plan on changing the numbers while they're in string form.

So that's just:

```js
function betterParse(stringNum) {
  const unformattedNum = stringNum.trim().split(", ").join("").split(",").join("");
  // Or if you're ok with only supporting browsers from 2020 onwards...

  return parseInt(unformattedNum);
  // ^ Assuming these are always whole numbers, otherwise use parseFloat instead
}
function isInRange(parsedNumber) {
  return parsedNumber >= 1000 && parsedNumber <= 100000;
}
```

Hope this helps

**Edit**: added the trimming from ggorlen's answer. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array with the range of your values:

```js
// helper
function range(start, end) {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
}
let values = range(1000, 10000);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.